# How do you add a scrolling div directly to a ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, html, scroll

I have the following code, but it doesn't put the scrolling div anywhere.  All the other combinations I've tried (such as placing the div around the table) results in some or other incorrect placement of the scroll bars.
This is the html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <div style="overflow: auto; width : 200px; height : 50px;">
      {{ form }}
    </div>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

My forms look like this:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['permissions'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['permissions'].choices = ((p.id, p.name) for p in Permission.objects.order_by("name"))
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
def group_edit(request, group_id, template_name="group_edit.html", extra_context=None, form_class=None):

    edit_group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=group_id)
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    form_class = form_class or GroupForm
    extra_context["edit_group"] = edit_group

    if request.method == "POST":
        form  = form_class(instance=edit_group, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("global_group_list"))
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=edit_group)

    extra_context["form"] = form

    return direct_to_template(
        request,
        template_name,
        extra_context=extra_context
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the DIV inside a table row like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr><td><div style="overflow: auto; width : 200px; height : 50px;">
      {{ form.as_p }}
    </div></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Okay I did that, shouldn't be a problem though, but it doesn't solve my problem.  It just adds an extra row to my table and insert the empty div there.  It doesn't actually encapsulate the {{ form }}.

Comment: If the DIV is inside the table, it should be in a row. See update.

Comment: that wouldn't work, in django {{form}} outputs <tr><td>.. for each field. Your could try this solution in combinatin with {{form.as_ul}}

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you show me the function which is outputting the form.

Comment: @JamesO, thanks for that. I was unaware that form is an alias for form.as_table

Comment: Actually both those worked and gave the same output.  How can I access {{ form }}?  I still have two fields having scroll applied, whereas I'd just like the content of one of the fields to be scrollable.  Will update my post!

Comment: Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template on how to get the form items.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a django problem, so the python code you posted really makes no difference. I think the issue is you want the table to have scroll bars, but keep the submit button separate?

You have two immediate options. you can wrap {{ form }} in a second table, so you have two nested tables. Alternately you can move the div and submit button to be outside your table, so that the table is wrapped with the div.

Either way what you have now won't work. any immediate child tag of a table tag, other than a tbody or a tr will be ignored.